# Why are .#<filename> files appearing whenever I edit a file

Tags: file, emacs, autosave

Say I'm editing `file.txt`. Before saving this file, a new file appears named `.#file.txt`. This file is a symlink pointing elsewhere on my machine.

I have read about Emacs auto-save and backup files. From my understanding, auto-save files take the form of `#filename#` while backup files take the form `filename~`.

I have disabled both auto-save and backup to learn more about this annoyance. I configured these with the following lines:

```
(setq auto-save-default nil)
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

Unfortunately the problem even after this configuration. Does anyone know what is causing the creation of the `.#file.txt` file? Could it be a lock file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [EmacsWiki AutoSave](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoSave#toc3)

> Be aware that symbolic links of the form “.#*” are not auto-save files
>   but interlocks to prevent the simultaneous editing of the same file.  See [Interlocking](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html#Interlocking) in the EmacsManual for details.